# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException in Java

Tags: java

when i try to run  below error code but getting error, i also used "givenArray[i] = sc.next(); or givenArray[i] = sc.nextLine(); " but still failing.
I tried many different ways but still got the same error.
it seems Scanner is unable to read the array
I need help with this code please, Thank you in advance.

Input provided:
Enter  length of first Array: 4 and hit enter,
Enter length of second Array: 4 and hit enter,
Enter First array: 2,3,4,5 and hit enter then it throws the below error.

```
 private static boolean firstAndLastTwoArray(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArry){



        int  firsIndexOFirstArray = firstArray[0];
        int lastIndexOfSecondArray = secondArry[secondArry.length -1];


        if (firsIndexOFirstArray == lastIndexOfSecondArray) {

            return true;

        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter  length of first Array: ");
        int firstArray = sc.nextInt();
        int[] givenArray = new int[firstArray];


        System.out.println("Enter length of second Array: ");
        int secondArray = sc.nextInt();
        int[] givenArray1 = new int[secondArray];



        for (int i = 0; i <firstArray; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter First array:");
            givenArray[i] = sc.nextInt();


            for (int k = 0; k <secondArray; k++){

                System.out.println("Enter Second array:");
                givenArray1[k] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Result is: " + firstAndLastTwoArray(givenArray,givenArray1));
    }
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at w3Resource.Exercise76.main(Exercise76.java:54)
```

Comment: The inner loop is using `i` where it should probably be using `k` (typo?). It is also using `givenArray` instead of `givenArray1`.

Comment: Also, why are you using nested loops anyway? You should probably have 2 separate loops: one to populate `givenArray` and one for `givenArray1`.

Comment: That is correct, it`s (typo), But that is not the issue.  using the nested loop to iterate  indexes  in "secondArray".

Comment: It works fine with typos fixed and 2 separate loops. Try it and see. When you have nested loops, you input the 2nd array `firstArray` times when you only want to enter it 1 time.

Comment: Please update the question to include the input that you are giving it through System.in.

Comment: I updated the question with Input data and all typos were fxied. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was resolved. i was adding come(,) after each input(or index), that was  issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter array elements one by one. Do not enter with comma separated. It will be considered as String not int.

Else, remove the for loop and get the array elements as comma separated using nextLine(), then split the input string based on ',' using string.split(",") which returns an array.